# PHP Get REST Api and parse JSON

Tags: php, json, api

I have done research and I can't seem to find a solution. I have a website running XenForo and added [XenAPI](https://github.com/Contex/XenAPI/) to the Software.

When you call the API: ( `api.php?action=authenticate&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD`) 
it returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "hash": "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08"
}
```

I am trying to find the "proper" way of capturing the JSON and decoding it. I hope you guys can help! **Note that I am looking for a example to learn from, because all other examples fail.**

Answer (score 0):

For simple requests with 1-2 params, you can use

```
$json = file_get_contents(url...);
$response = json_decode($json, true);
```

For more difficult queries use curl extension.
For full web-applications use Guzzle - curl wrapper for communicates with API.

Comment: Will check on that. Not sure if my host has file_get enabled

Comment: It returns a empty response, tested by printing the 'json' var.

Comment: Be sure, that API allow GET request and you set required params in string in url. Also try to duplicate request in browser. Usually, they have the same behaviour.

Comment: Still empty. I think my host has the file_get off

Comment: As I know, file_get_contents() cannot be disabled, but it can be configured. Try ini_get('allow_url_fopen'). If it return 0 or false, you will have to use curl. By the way, checkout curl extension existing in your php.